# Errors & Warnings when running ggplots

Tags: r, grid

When I use ggplot to explore some data sets, I'm getting a warning which I do not understand:

```
Error in grid.newpage() : 
  unable to open file 'C:/Users/nicob/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpoPyQxB/f51adc22dcbf4cecb1b1365264f7d30b.png' for writing
In addition: Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to open file 'C:/Users/nicob/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpoPyQxB/08b81a1197bf4e179fb4552111f09c8a.png' for writing
```

It doesn't really stop me from exploring data (since the plots still render) but it's just mucking up my console so much (on R Studio). Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code that generated the warnings?

Comment: you seem to have systemic filesystem permissions issues. not surprising (it's windows) but you shld check permissions.

Comment: Yeah that's the path `tempfile()` returns. Make sure you write permission to `AppData/Local/Temp`